# Genymotion device name

Tags: android, adb, appium, genymotion

I'm creating some automated web mobile app tests , using appium with Java. And I'm using genymotion emulator.
I'm setting some capabilities, like

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "TheDeviceName");
```

But I'm not sure about the device name, from cmd when I type adb devices -l I get :

```
>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
192.168.54.101:5555    device product:vbox86p model:AminaPhone device:vbox86p
```

This is the code i used :

```
package com.example;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.BrowserType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class FirstAppiumTest {


// create instance for appium driver
    AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;
    @Test

    public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,BrowserType.CHROME);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM,Platform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Android");
        //cap.setCapability("udid","192.168.54.101:5555");

        //cap.setCapability("AVD", "emulator-5554");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub/status"), cap);
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        System.out.println("Title "+driver.getTitle());
        System.out.println("SetUp is successful and Appium Driver is launched successfully");
        driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("test_selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();

    }


}
```

What is the name that i should in the desiredcapabilities and in the appium configuration ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify:
"adb devices" give you the device ID, not the device name.
moreover, it's not possible to launch genymotion emulator directly from appium capabilities so you have to options:

If its important for you to also launch the emulator before test starts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28961477/7368913

if it's not important to launch the emulator, simply add the capability:

```
cap.setCapability("udid, "192.168.54.101:5555");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is when I use a real device , I put the name displayed by ; adb devices. and the test runs ok. But with emulator with the same code, nothing happens. I thought appium is not recognizing the emulator. And i don't need to lunch the emulator by it self.I launch it before running the code.

Comment: when using a genymotion emulator - put a generic device name capability `capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");`
did you try adding "udid" to the capabilities? its exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you. I tried both of them and nothing is happening on the emulator :(

Comment: can you send me the code where you instantiate the driver?

Comment: sorry for being so late, i posted the code that i used.

Comment: Victoria, i was not around, did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you David,  still not able to launch the test on an emulator.

Comment: Amina you also face the same problem? I can send you my setup() function if you want to try.